# MongoDB query with custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using a MongoDB database and storing users' location, then I use this location to find the nearby users of a user with a custom maximum distance using a function getDistance that finds the distance between two coordinate points.
my question is what is the best way to perform this query?
currently I load all documents and loop over each of them and compare the result of getDistance to the maximum distance value, but this is very inefficient. I read about `methods` and `statics` in mongoose and I feel I could take advantage of them, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Comment: I was just reading about it, thank you!